# Cannot handle 'OUT' Parameters in SOAP PHP Cient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, client

I'm trying to consume a web service which has an `out` parameter in its parameter list.

How can I handle these `out` parameters in a PHP SOAP client?

Comment: Someone has down voted. People who haven't worked with any middleware does not about this type of issues. This type of issues are very uncommon and very few people know about these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that this cannot be achieved with php SOAP libraries. Instead you have to use SOAP requests generated using SOAP UI and then post it with in header with CURL request. Please comment if you need exact code.